# Product method in c#

Tags: c#, python, product, python-itertools

I am working with python, and I am implementing my code to c# and in python there is method "product", anyone knows if there is something similar in c#? if not maybe someone can put me on a track of how to write this function by myself?

example of product:

```
a=[[[(1, 2), (3, 4)], [(5, 6), (7, 8)], [(9, 10), (11, 12)]], [[(13, 14), (15, 16)]]]

b= product(*a)
```

output:

```
([(1, 2), (3, 4)], [(13, 14), (15, 16)])
([(5, 6), (7, 8)], [(13, 14), (15, 16)])
([(9, 10), (11, 12)], [(13, 14), (15, 16)])
```

Comment: Give example of the `product` method.

Comment: Perhaps you could explain what the "product" method does in Python? It's not just a simply multiply funciton I take it?

Comment: Presumably the OP is referring to [the `product` function in `itertools`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product), but they should clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you mean [itertools.product](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) (it looks like it from the example given):

```
public static List< Tuple<T, T> > Product<T>(List<T> a, List<T> b)
    where T : struct
{
    List<Tuple<T, T>> result = new List<Tuple<T, T>>();

    foreach(T t1 in a)
    {
        foreach(T t2 in b)
            result.Add(Tuple.Create<T, T>(t1, t2));
    }

    return result;
}
```

n.b. `struct` here means that `T` must be a value type or a structure. Change it to `class` if you need to throw in objects such as `List`s, but be aware of potential referencing issues.

Then as a driver:

```
List<int> listA = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 };
List<int> listB = new List<int>() { 7, 8, 9 };

List<Tuple<int, int>> product = Product<int>(listA, listB);
foreach (Tuple<int, int> tuple in product)
    Console.WriteLine(tuple.Item1 + ", " + tuple.Item2);
```

Output:

```
1, 7
1, 8
1, 9
2, 7
2, 8
2, 9
3, 7
3, 8
3, 9
```

Answer (score 0):

For a product function valid over number of lists, you can use my `CrossProductFunction.CrossProduct` code [here](https://github.com/Arithmomaniac/cs-tools/blob/master/CrossProduct.cs):

```
List<List<Tuple<int>>> a = new List<List<Tuple<int>>> { /*....*/ }
IEnumerable<List<Tuple<int>>> b = CrossProductFunctions.CrossProduct(a)
```

Currently, it doesn't accept `repeat` argument like `itertools.product` does, but it is otherwise similar in functionality and design.

Answer (score -3):

Here is syntax for writing function in c#:

```
public void product()
        {
          ..........
          .........
        }
```

**Link:**

http://www.dotnetspider.com/forum/139241-How-write-function-c-.net.aspx

Can get information about all kinds of functions in c# on this link.

Comment: And how does this answer the question?

Comment: he simply asked "how to write function by myself?"

Comment: You forgot the word "this" in the sentence, which implies he meant hwo to write the function `product()` and not functions in general.

Comment: yes, this is product function which i have written. nothing wrong in it.

Comment: I don't agree with that. He want's to have the Python function() of `itertools.product()` in C# (a conversion). Your whole method body is missing, which is the most important and difficult task.

Comment: not mentioned anywhere in his question about 'itertools.product()' thats what every ones comment is asking him below the question.

Comment: OP wouldn't have talked about porting Python to C#, explained the product function, and asked "if there is something similar in c#?" if they only wanted to know how to write C# functions.